# aws-sdk bucket.getObject: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' error

Tags: angular, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, cors

I am trying to get an object from S3 bucket adn have configured the CORS on my bucket but still getting

> No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'

error

I have already tried all the various fixes available online but nothing seems to work.

My angular code

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import * as AWS from 'aws-sdk';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})

export class AppComponent {
  title = 'awsapp';

  ngOnInit() {
    AWS.config.credentials = new AWS.Credentials({
      accessKeyId: 'my-access-key',
      secretAccessKey: 'my-secret-key'
    });

    AWS.config.update({
      region: 'us-east-1'
    });
  }

  getObject() {

    let s3 = new AWS.S3();

    const params = {
      Bucket: 'my-bucket-name',
      Key: 'testfolder/tests3.txt'
    };

    s3.getObject(params, function (err, data) {
      if (err) {
        console.error(err);
      }
      else {
        // const string = new TextDecoder('utf-8').decode(data.Body);
        console.log(data);
      }
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

CORS needs to be configured on the server-side. Add this on server cors configuration

```
<AllowedHeader>*</AllowedHeader>
```

Comment: I already have my CORS confgured on my AWS console as below
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CORSConfiguration xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">
<CORSRule>
    <AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin>
    <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>PUT</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>POST</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>DELETE</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedHeader>*</AllowedHeader>
</CORSRule>
</CORSConfiguration>

Comment: Yes I added the CORS configuration to S3 bucket only in AWS S3 management console.